# iOS facebook SDK: Login already authenticated

Tags: objective-c, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I have had the Facebook iOS SDK running in an app I've been working on for a few months. At this point I am mostly using the SDK for SSO purposes.

Since I have started using iOS 6.0 I have been seeing an issue where the "Login to use your FB account with MY_APP" modal is blocking my current view.
The odd thing is that the user is already authenticated and apparently authorized to use my app. This is proven by the fact that I can get the user's email address and such.

It is also important to note that if I click the "X" it will close and everything is fine (user is authenticated/authorized). If I login as it tells me, it shows the "MY_APP is already authorized" modal which I cannot click the "Okay" button but I can click the "X" which again drops me back into my view with the user authenticated and authorized.

Here you can see the it:

[image]

To authenticate I am calling the following method in the `appdelegate`:

```
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
```

The following are the relevant FB methods in my appdelegate:

```
// FACEBOOK STUFF
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"email", nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
                                         }];    
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session 
                      state:(FBSessionState)state
                      error:(NSError *)error {
    // FBSample logic
    // Any time the session is closed, we want to display the login controller (the user
    // cannot use the application unless they are logged in to Facebook). When the session
    // is opened successfully, hide the login controller and show the main UI.
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
            FBCacheDescriptor *cacheDescriptor = [FBFriendPickerViewController cacheDescriptor];
            [cacheDescriptor prefetchAndCacheForSession:session];
            [self sendAuthenticationStatusChangedNotification];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            // FBSample logic
            // Once the user has logged in, we want them to be looking at the root view.
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            //[self showLoginView];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:error.localizedDescription
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }    
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // FBSample logic
    // We need to handle URLs by passing them to FBSession in order for SSO authentication
    // to work.
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I noticed that this is happing on one of my phones but not the other. The phone that wasn't working had an older version of the FB app installed. Updating the FB app stopped this issue from happening. I am still interested in a fix to avoid others from experiencing the same issue.

**EDIT 2**

The issue went away for a little but now is back even with the new facebook app installed.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me actually turned out to be a silly one.  I was calling

```
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
```

two times due to a button click event that was wired up twice.  As soon as it was only being called once, the issue went away!